# Strange Subversion files in /tmp

Tags: svn, apache

I've noticed that there are a few files in my /tmp directory that apparently belong to Subversion:

auth/, config, README.txt and servers

The interesting thing is that these files belong to www-data which is what Apache runs as, yet my SVN install has nothing to do with Apache, and I'm not even using mod_dav_svn or anything like that... The timestamps on these files are from within a few days ago and I've tried deleting them before only to see them recreated later.

Anyone have any idea where these files are coming from, why they are there and why they belong to www-data?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to uninstall Subversion and delete the files. Then reinstall. Then you can observe, whether theese files come from the setup and also wether they belong to www-data by default. Because I guess that your distributon decides that the subversion package installs with user www-data.